# Unfavorited question showing up as favorited on main account

Tags: bug, bookmarks

Approximately two weeks ago, I favorited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380266/underline-first-letter-in-checkbox). I unfavorited it two days later. It was removed from the favorites list on my [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342319/mmking?tab=favorites), but it is still on the favorites list on my [Stack Exchange account](https://stackexchange.com/users/5459898/mmking?tab=favorites) (it is the third from the bottom).

I believe the problem is not caching, since I have waited two weeks already. It's not a big problem, but it kind of bothers me when I see a question on my favorites list that I do not want to follow.

I found [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216327/wrong-number-of-favorites-in-network-profile-for-some-users) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248540/why-is-this-favorite-appearing-in-my-network-proflile?rq=1) on the main Meta site regarding this, but neither of them has been answered.

When will this be fixed?

Comment: Favorites seems to be the flakiest feature on SE. Good luck.

Comment: This is a cache problem. Should be fixed in 6-8 weeks. Don't worry.

Comment: Favoriting this question :)

Comment: `6-8 weeks`. You're unfavourite is in the mail.

Comment: @Zanon Your 6 to 8 weeks are up... And now this question is showing up on my favorites list because I accidentally favorited it. :(

Comment: I saw that you've unfavorited and the question is still in your SE list. After 1 one year, now, we can say that's not cache (or, at least, not a good caching approach).

Comment: Related problem [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324051/user-profile-favorite-tab-questions-items-data-not-correct-on-stack-exchange?cb=1).