# User profile favorite tab questions items data not correct on Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, questions, profile-page, bookmarks

I do not have any favorite question in my profile on Stack Overflow (below Snap).

[image: My Profile snapshot]

But when I visit my profile from another browser on Stack Exchange (incognito or from which I'm not signed in). It displays favorite items, and it was showing two question items earlier, but when I rechecked the questions from my profile, now it is showing one item. I think it's a bug on Stack Exchange (the below Snap is showing Favorite question).

[image: Stack Exchange profile]

[My profile on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/6019636/mjunaidsalaat?tab=favorites) with one item of favorite question.

[My profile on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4727212/mjunaidsalaat?tab=favorites) with no favorite questions.

I think this is clear, but I will be available for any questions.

PS: It's okay on Stack Overflow; this is on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Weird. Do you remember whether you ever had favourited that question?

Comment: I do not remember exactly, But I think yes. I added it to my favorites but then removed it. But I did it again today, It was showing two items earlier then I opened both questions and which were not stared. I clicked them to star and clicked again to remove. Then It was only one item here.

Comment: Probably caching - try waiting a while (perhaps 24 hours).

Comment: Same question on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216327/wrong-number-of-favorites-in-network-profile-for-some-users

Comment: What happens when you go [to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000427/filtering-multi-select-dropdown-options) and favourite, then unfavourite it?

Comment: @Oded, favoriting and unfavoriting again may not solve the problem. The same was done in this [related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296258/unfavorited-question-showing-up-as-favorited-on-main-account). Also, the related report is reaching 1 year, so it's also not caching.

Answer (score -1):

Is probably a case of http://shouldiblamecaching.com as the question marker itself says:

> 0 users have marked this question as favorite

And the question indeed has 0 favorites. Give it 24 hours and this should sort itself out.

Comment: It's been more than 24 hours and its still there. This is not a caching issue.

Comment: Just wait [about 6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/292385).

Comment: This is **not** caching. This [related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296258/unfavorited-question-showing-up-as-favorited-on-main-account) has the same problem and is almost 1 year old.

Comment: @Zanon I cache results, I forget to validate cached results. It's consistent with observations.